# What does it mean "data?.name" on below code

Tags: xamarin

Could someone explain what it means `data?.name` on below code:

public static async Task Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)

```
{
    log.Info($"C# HTTP trigger function processed a request. RequestUri={req.RequestUri}");

    // parse query parameter
    string name = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
        .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "name", true) == 0)
        .Value;

    // Get request body
    dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();

    // Set name to query string or body data
    name = name ?? data?.name;


    return name == null
        ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
        : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name));
}
```

Used at this link: https://blog.xamarin.com/creating-a-serverless-backend-for-mobile-apps/

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

That's the C# 6 [Null Conditional](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) operator

If data is null, it will prevent data.name from throwing an exception, instead returning a null

Comment: Great!  Thanks very much.